# After updating from 10.6 pimcore v to 11 version, facing version count issue

Tags: php, symfony4, pimcore

I have updated pimcore 10.6 v to pimcore 11, followed all the steps as per pimcore documentation.

i executed 2 commands. In the version command getting below error attached

command => php pimcore10.6_migrate_o_prefixes_versions.php

```
Exception {#1022
   #message: "Call to undefined method seto_versionCount in class Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Tier"
#code: 0
#file: "./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php"
#line: 231
trace: {
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php:231 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php:189 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/AbstractModel.php:170 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Model/Dao/DaoTrait.php:39 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/Concrete/Dao.php:68 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/AbstractObject.php:244 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/Element/AbstractElement.php:644 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/DataObject/Concrete.php:736 { …}
Pimcore\Model\DataObject\Concrete->__wakeup() {}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/lib/Tool/Serialize.php:31 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/Version.php:290 { …}
./vendor/pimcore/pimcore/models/Version.php:413 { …}
./pimcore10.6_migrate_o_prefixes_versions.php:26 {
› $data = null;
› $data = $version->getData();
›
}
}
}
```

actually this version command is there for migrating versions from 10.6v to 11.0, in my case while executing causing above error.

can anyone let me know how to solve this?